# Single quote string causing syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: vba

I have the following email to add: jan.o'malley@test.com

The following code is used to update the person info:

```
update_info = "update names set " & _
                        "   email= '" & Me.email & "', " & _
                        "   name= '" & Me.name & "', " & _
                        "where id = " & Me.id
CurrentDb.Execute update_info
```

When I try to add the above email I get this error:

[image]

What should I do to be able to store (and use) this email?

Comment: Use `Replace(Me.email, "'", "''")` instead.

Comment: replace the `'` tihe `''` by using `replace` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

Comment: You're leaving yourself wide open for an SQL injection attack there.

Comment: The `Replace(Me.email, "'", "''")` returns 0 instead of the email addres.

Comment: Then check how you used it. It works fine for me.

Comment: @jsheeran why is that?

Comment: Just keep in mind that eventually you are going to realize that you are much better off using parameters.